# Passing objects from template to view using Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, javascript-objects

I am trying to figure out the architecture for the following app:

1. The user is presented with a table.
2. Each table cell has several fields the user will be filling in.
3. There is a general submit button: when clicked on all the input data (along with some calculated data per cell based on the input values) should pass to a Django view.

Here are the following questions:

1. Can I organize the data structure as a set of objects in a way that each object will correspond to a table cell, whereas the Master object, that will eventually be passed to the Django view, will be a set of those objects?
2. If so, how to pass the Master object from a template to view using Django?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a bit of html, so we can visualize what you have now.

Anyway if you click on submit your view should see all the fields using `request.POST`

Comment: Thanks. I do not have a complete HTML yet I am trying to figure out the architecture before I start doing it, hence my question. Basically what I am asking is: 1. Is it possible to create an object in HTML/JS whose members will contain data from the fields? 2. Is it possible in any way to pass that object into python view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Is it possible to create an object in HTML/JS whose members will contain data from the fields?**

You can't create an object in html/JS, but you can build your code up to display or request data from an object in Django.

Say for example, you have a model Foo

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    GENDER = (
      ('F', 'Female'),
      ('M', 'Male'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER)
```

And your template looks like this

```
<body>
<form action="?" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="150" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>
            <select name="gender">
                <option value="F">Female</option>
                <option value="M">Male</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

If you fill in the fields and click submit, then you can handle the data in your view.

```
def add_foo(request):
    if request.method == "POST": # Check if the form is submitted
        foo = Foo() # instantiate a new object Foo, don't forget you need to import it first
        foo.name = request.POST['name']
        foo.gender = request.POST['gender']
        foo.save() # You need to save the object, for it to be stored in the database
        #Now you can redirect to another page
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
    else: #The form wasn't submitted, show the template above
        return render(request, 'path/to/template.html')
```

That last bit also answered question 2, i think. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! After your comment above I have been thinking about it myself and came to the conclusion that having assigned different HTML names to the forms' fields and then using request.POST to retrieve them in the view would be the right solution for me.